# please advise how to fix error while starting h20 through py console

Tags: h2o

After installing `h2o` couldn't initialize server and receiving error while trying to start.

> h2o.exceptions.h2oServererror: Server process terminated with error code 1
>
> > > import h2o
> > >       h2o.init()
> > >       Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54321..... not found.
> > >       Attempting to start a local H2O server...
> > >       ; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
> > >         Starting server from C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\bin\h2o.jar
> > >         Ice root: C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvyk4vufd
> > >         JVM stdout: C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvyk4vufd\h2o_Prem_started_from_python.out
> > >         JVM stderr: C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvyk4vufd\h2o_Prem_started_from_python.err
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o.py", line 252, in init
> > >           "connected.", "not found."))
> > >         File "C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\connection.py", line 318, in open
> > >           conn._cluster = conn._test_connection(retries, messages=_msgs)
> > >         File "C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\connection.py", line 588, in _test_connection
> > >           % (self._base_url, max_retries, "\n".join(errors)))
> > >       h2o.exceptions.H2OConnectionError: Could not establish link to the H2O cloud http://localhost:54321 after 5 retries
> > >       [08:22.10] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
> > >       [08:24.37] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
> > >       [08:26.59] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
> > >       [08:28.84] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
> > >       [08:31.15] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o.py", line 261, in init
    min_mem_size=mmin, ice_root=ice_root, port=port, extra_classpath=extra_classpath)
  File "C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\server.py", line 121, in start
    mmax=max_mem_size, mmin=min_mem_size)
  File "C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\server.py", line 328, in _launch_server
    raise H2OServerError("Server process terminated with error code %d"'%proc.returncode)
h2o.exceptions.H2OServerError:Server process terminated with error code 1

Comment: Could you please elaborate with error log ? Also, how are you starting h2o on which enviornment

Comment: sorry. I have added error log to question now. Kindly advise how to fix

Comment: Are you using a windows instance ? Is firewall blocking port 54321